# How to add Windows Phone 8.1 app development support using Javascript in Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013. I want to develop apps for Windows Phone 8.1 using Javascript but there is no option for it. What should I do? Here is the screenshot of my New Project dialog in Javascript[image: Javascript New Project dialog]